# How to filter a collection with two values from two different lists?

Tags: c#, linq, filter, collections, iteration

I am trying to create a calculator for Pokemon type weaknesses. Say, if "dark" is chosen, I'd want to get a filtered list of Pokemon that are weak to "dark" (please note that Pokemon may be dual-typed so it's necessary to check that the second type doesn't cancel out the weakness of the first type). I have two separate lists that contain both the weaknesses and strengths of every type. The closest piece of code I have achieved so far is this

`pokedex = pokedex.Where(c => c.type1 != NotEffList[0] && c.type2 != NotEffList[0] && (c.type1 == SuperEffList[0] || c.type2 == SuperEffList[0]));`

In the case of "dark": SuperEffList contains items "ghost" and "psychic", NotEffList contains "dark", "fairy" and "fighting".

This would work fine if I could replace the accessing of (only) the first item [0] with all items on the list. In other words, I want to get a collection of all Pokemon where either type1 or type2 is an item from SuperEffList while type1 nor type2 is NOT any item from NotEffList.

Iteration doesn't seem to work because the filtered collection would end up being just the result of the last iteration. I can't help but think that there's a simple LINQ solution to this but after spending hours and hours with this I need to look for a little help here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing the data in two seperate `List<string>` isn't the ideal way to store the data.

I would recommend using object oriented programming model, you should consider using the following construct instead.

First create an enum holding all the possible types:

```
[Flags]
enum PokemonType
{
    None = 0,
    Electro = 1 << 1,
    Water = 1 << 2,
    Grass = 1 << 3,
}
```

Notice:

I have declared the enum with the `[Flags]` attribute with this it is possible to "combine" multiple enums eg. an Electro + Grass Pokemon can be defined as `PokemonType.Electro | PokemonType.Grass`

---

Now defined a base class that will be inherited for all possible pokemon types:

```
abstract class TypeBase
{
    public abstract PokemonType Type { get; }
    public abstract PokemonType WeakAgainstType { get; }


    public virtual bool IsWeakTo(PokemonType type) => WeakAgainstType.HasFlag(type);
}
```

Notice:

The base class could be easily extended to your needs eg. `EffectiveAgainstType`, `ImmuneAgainstType` and so on...

---

Here a possible implementation of a `WaterType` which is weak again `Electro` and `Grass`.

```
class WaterType : TypeBase
{
    public override PokemonType Type { get; } = PokemonType.Water;
    public override PokemonType WeakAgainstType { get; } => PokemonType.Electro | PokemonType.Grass;
}
```

Futher you can define a specific Pokemon with this:

```
class Squirtle : WaterType
{
    //I did declare IsWeakTo as virtual to enable overriding it
    //maybe a certain pokemon has a unique ability that makes it weak or not weak against certain stuff
    public override bool IsWeakTo(PokemonType type)
    {
        if (type == PokemonType.Water)
            return true;

        return base.IsWeakTo(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you add some extra information about why you choose this solution.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - maybe tomorrow, it’s a pain in the a** to type on phone, sorry